# Debugging power connected iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I'm experiencing a problem where my application is behaving strangely when a power cable is connected. There is a simple button that triggers a segue showing a new view. Occasionally when a power cable is plugged in, the segue is triggered twice in a row and eventually results in a crash.

What options are available for debugging this sort of behaviour? As I understand, there are no power options available for the simulator to simulate power being added or removed or cables being connected. I also am not aware of any way to debug on an actual device where a cable is not continuously connected.

Does anyone have theories about what might be happeneing here? I've looked into the application lifecycle to try and get an idea of what happens internally when power is added, but have yet to find anything.

Comment: more like your device or cable is faulty, it have nothing to do with code

Comment: @Tj3n It seems very strange that a power cable (faulty or not) could cause this sort of behaviour in an application. Do you have any ideas around what is happening in the system here?

Comment: It can really, the faulty electrical can affect the touch screen and cause weird behavior like random touch, your button there is just coincident, im sure that it never happen in simulator right

Comment: @Tj3n I don't know. As far as I know there is no way to simulate power being connected or disconnected with the simulator, so it's not possible to simulate this scenario in any way